# How show image(s) from Stream(Responce) in a PictureBox - Specific URL

Tags: c#, stream, picturebox, httpwebresponse

here is my codes :

```
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.flowercity.com/");
    req.Method = "GET";
    req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
    req.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
    req.Timeout = 25000;

    HttpWebResponse res = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

    Stream Stream = res.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Stream);
    string reader_str = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

how can i grab loaded images in Stream and show them **one by one** in a PictureBox?

**Edit 1 :**
please see my url, it's not an image, it's a web site and we have a web site in Stream.
so the codes below does not work :

```
    Image img = Image.FromStream(Stream);
    PictureBox1.Image = img;
```

**Edit 2 :**
i can not use `HtmlAgilityPack` for getting image **urls**.
there is no specific url for every image and need to show **previous loaded images in stream**.

Comment: The page is just HTML. You need to use something like HtmlAgilityPack to comb the HTML looking for images.

Comment: the url of images is like this : web site/124124124.blablabla so in every load i get a different image and i want the first loaded image from req.GetResponse();

Comment: my question is where are those first loaded images and how can i grab them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comment by vcsjones, your stream is that of the index page of the website. Within it are image tags . Like your browser does for you when you navigate to the site in question, you need to download the images separately.

The most reliable method for doing that is probably to use regular expressions to search the webpage (the one you're loading in your example code) for those links. You can obviously try to load the page as an XML document but XML parsers are very strict on validity. Most webpage authors unfortunately aren't so a more "loose" search of the webpage for your links probably works best.

Your code should work if you feed it a direct image link. Your challenge now is to get those direct links from the page you're loading.

Edit

Your webpage looks something like this:

```
<html>
<title>welcome to the flower page</title>
<img src="flower.jpg"/>
</html>
```

(shortened for simplicity's sake)

You need to read through the text you are getting to find where the images are stored on the webserver and then open a separate http connection to download each image.

Comment: hi Markus, please see my comment.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how webpages work, MoonLight. The data in the stream you are opening contains only the text of the webpage and links to the images, not the images themselves.

Comment: Have a look at the edit in my answer, the comment size could not hold a proper explanation.